# How to declare and define 2 Dimensional strings

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I want to have two strings corresponding to one index. For example, I want to define values like this:

```
str[0][0] = "String1";
str[0][1] = "String2";

str[1][0] = "String3";
str[1][1] = "String4";
//etc.....
```

How can I declare such array/string?

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "2D string." If anything, the code suggests you want a **3D** string, aka an array of arrays of strings (since strings themselves are 1D arrays of characters). You might want to explain why you want to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare and define like this:

```
    const char * str[2][2] = {
            { "String1", "String2" },
            { "String3", "String4" }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
char* str[2][2];

str[0][0] = "String1";
str[0][1] = "String2";

str[1][0] = "String3";
str[1][1] = "String4";
```

Should work.

It's not *a string*, it's an array of arrays of "strings" (char pointers), but it looks like what you're asking for.

Comment: This is what I did, and it works as well, but then what bothers me is that we need to allocate the memory first using malloc() and then only we can define them as there is no memory allocated for str1, str2 etc.

Comment: If you hard-code string like that compiler automatically allocates memory for your strings and assign pointers to memory to your array items. But if need to change content of your strings, then you need to manage memory allocation yourself.
I wasn't in 'C' for quite some time, and I can be wrong, but I think I still remember this correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

This explanation with C# Code

1. Create variable array 
   Example

   private ArrayList m_oArrayList = new ArrayList();
2. Create variable for member to arraylist
3. Create properties to return value for variable poin 2
4. Create properties to patch poin 2 to add in arraylist
5. Create properties to patch in index array list 
   Example

public ClassMembersPoin2 this[int index]
{

```
get { return (ClassMembersPoin2 )m_oArrayList [index]; }
```

}